# VBA Excel - Error when trying to create range using a function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure where the problem is with this bit of code I worked out. I have the following public declarations and function:

```
Public g_0 As Range
Public Enum RngType
    A = 1
    H = 2
    X = 3
End Enum


Function RngMk(csTable As String, csType As RngType, Optional csHeaderName As Variant = "")

Dim str As String

Select Case csType
    Case RngType.A
        If csHeaderName = "" Then
            str = csTable & "[#All]"
        Else:
            str = csTable & "[[#All],[" & csHeaderName & "]]"
        End If
    Case RngType.H
        If csHeaderName = "" Then
            str = csTable & "[#Headers]"
        Else:
            str = csTable & "[[#Headers],[" & csHeaderName & "]]"
        End If
    Case RngType.X
        If csHeaderName = "" Then
            str = csTable
        Else:
            str = csTable & Chr(91) & csHeaderName & Chr(93)
        End If
End Select

RngMk = Range(str)

End Function
```

The code above should establish any range inside a given table ListObject. However, when I add the following into a Sub

```
g_0 = RngMk("Table1", A, "Name")

g_0.Select
```

I get the error "91 - Object variable or With block variable not set". I'm not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: When assigning a range, you need to use the `Set` keyword, so the line should be `Set g_0 = RngMk("Table1", A, "Name")`

Comment: I added `Set`, and it did get rid of `Run-time error '91'`, however now I get a new error: `Run-time error '424': Object required`

Comment: Is your variable `A` set to be a `RngType` object which is required by your function?

Comment: Are you saying I should add an object type after `Public Enum RngType` for example `Public Enum RngType As Long`

Comment: I believe the function is actually returning a concatenated string. The problem would seem to be later where `g_0 = RngMk("Table1", A, "Name")` should be more like `Set g_0 = Range(RngMk("Table1", A, "Name"))`.

Comment: what does the *Immediate Window* show when `?RngMk("Table1", A, "Name")` is thrown at it?

Comment: You need to add `Set` both in the last line of your function *and* when you call the function; `Set RngMk = Range(str)` and `Set g_0 = RngMk("Table1", A, "Name")`   You should also define the return type of your function as `Range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function use

```
Set RngMk = Range(str)
```

This should solve your issue.

And still "set" g_0 = rngmk(.....)

Comment: That did it! Thank you `@Kyle` and thank you everyone for suggesting to add `Set` before my expressions

Comment: You are very welcome. I never realized a function can actually return an object, so thank you!